# Microsoft 365 / Office 365 organization name change -- change names or set up new account?

Tags: office365, rename

Our business is going through a rebrand and we have been using Microsoft/Office 365 for 6+ years. As we approach the rebrand, I'm wondering how best to handle the 365 setup/migration. Would it make more sense to try to rename/realias everything, or just start from scratch with a new account. I've read that some things are very hard to change or don't change (such as the M365 companyname.onmicrosoft.com domain).

If anyone has any suggestion, or pointers or best practices, I would appreciate it. Google searching doesn't help much, it mostly brings results on the Office365->Microsoft365 name change.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've logged in through your browser on https://www.office.com with an admin account, you can head to the admin center for any of the tasks you mention:

- you can change the organization's profile (name, address, business details) in https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/Settings/OrganizationProfile
- you can add a new domain in https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home#/Domains (you can even get rid of the onmicrosoft stuff ..).
- you can then change the access for each user in https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/users . You can choose from any domain(s) you have setup in the previous step. You can select multiple users and then select "change domain".

The admin center really is quite straightforward, and you should find anything you need for the migration. In case of troubles, I'd recommend to ask for support directly through the `help & support` tab in the admin center.

If you have a lot of accounts, I'd ask the suppport if they have a migration assistant available which lets you automate some tasks.

Comment: Thanks. I understand these changes are possible and know how to make them, but is it best practice to change these settings instead of setting up a new account or tenant?

Comment: @stormdrain you might want to consider asking your question on https://serverfault.com/ stackexchange community, which is specialised on network administration